# How to complete a circular shape using an array modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How would I use the array modifier to duplicate this pattern all the way around the top and bottom circle faces? Whenever I try to use the array modifier, the pattern just copies next to itself. Its hopefully going to be a grenade. Ive added the blend file in case anyone can help. Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of circular array addon download [here](http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.in/2013/11/addon-circle-array.html)

[New link for addon](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WFm40YD09B6O6SYX4j548yGyNnjKRZwQ)

Go to edit mode and with the shift select remove the top and bottom circles. Press <kbd>P</kbd> and select **Selection**

Now in the object mode select the mesh and Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
and select rotation & Scale press <kbd>F6</kbd> and click location tick mark.

Now in the modifiers tab add 8 count and press search bar and type **Circle Array** and your done.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful vase you got there ;) You don't need this addon if you use object offset but it makes things more straight forward I guess.

Comment: Thanks atek but the links are dead. Much appreciated though

Comment: Solved.  Had to create an empty in the center and rotate the pattern on the axis.  Thanks again for your help guys

Comment: @obloquy new link added for the addon